# Windows forms - mac - xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin-studio

Beginner question here, I'm learning to code and have been working with C# for a few weeks.
Now I am trying out with Windows.Forms and so far I haven't been sure on what kind of solution I am suppose to load. I am using a Mac and Tamarin Studio.  Xamarin only offers Xamarin.Forms but I'm not sure about that.
Any helping hands out there ?

Comment: WinForms must be developed on Windows in Visual Studio or SharpDevelop. There is no visual designer in Xamarin Studio, but you can try GTK# development.

Comment: is there no similar possibility , something like mac.forms ?

Comment: @LexLi thanks - next up Parallel Desktop

Comment: curious on why you want to study WinForms. Now Xamarin.Forms, Eto.Forms and WPF offer more than it, and can support more scenarios.

Answer (score 6):

Xamarin Studio is only for cross platform app development. Meaning you can code in C# your Android and iOS app. At most, you can develop a Console project but that's about it.

Xamarin.Forms is not to be confused with Windows Forms (WinForms).

> **Xamarins.Forms** Xamarin.Forms is a cross-platform UI toolkit that allows developers to easily create native user interface layouts that can be shared across Android, iOS, and Windows Phone. ([Source](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/))
>
> **WindowsForms** Windows Forms (WinForms) is a graphical (GUI) class library included as a part of Microsoft .NET Framework, providing a platform to write rich client applications for desktop, laptop, and tablet PCs. ([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms))

So to answer your question, if you want to build a Windows App using Windows Forms (though I would recommend using WPF as it's more modern), you will need to do that on Windows using either Visual Studio or another compatible IDE.